# Kubuntu Alt+Tab Task Switcher ignores its own setting & refuses to page through in reverse

Tags: kde, desktop-environment, kubuntu, kwin

Here's a screenshot of the seemingly relevant settings.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (Forward) works; <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (Reverse) does nothing.

Any suggestions for a fix or where exactly I should direct a bug report?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Bugs can be filed [here](http://bugs.kde.org). I actually find people there quite unresponsive. The [forum](http://forum.kde.org), however, is very helpful, if you get nothing useful here.

Comment: thanks. would mark correct if it were an answer

Comment: Good point. I should have read your question more thoroughly. I've changed it into an answer.

Comment: I confirm the bug is present in Kubuntu 16.04 and 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any suggestions for a fix or where exactly I should direct a bug report?

Bugs can be filed [here](http://bugs.kde.org/). I actually find people there quite unresponsive. The [forum](http://forum.kde.org/), however, is very helpful, if you get no other useful answers here.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the reason is that **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>** translates to **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>** which switches the keyboard layout and consecutive **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>** which traverses the opened applications in the non-reversed order. I think this is a bug and it is really uncomfortable for anyone with more than one keyboard layout.

It looks this is [an old bug which was fixed](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=174142)

However in Kubuntu 18.04 it appears again.

```
09:40:05:~$ plasmashell --version
plasmashell 5.12.6
09:40:10:~$ kf5-config --version
Qt: 5.9.5
KDE Frameworks: 5.44.0
kf5-config: 1.0
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't think that could be my issue though because I only have 1 keyboard layout & Alt + Shift doesn't seem to be an enabled shortcut for it.

Under Input Devices> Keyboard Hardware & Layout, I found an option to use Alt + Shift that way, but it's not selected. However, under Misc. I see something about handling Ctrl & Alt special keys in a server, so I will try that one & report back if it works

Comment: I set the handle ctrl & alt keys in server option & clicked restore to defaults in window switcher settings. No immediate change. But upon restart it finally works. (sorry for ambiguity on which solved it)

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed considered a somewhat "bug"-ish, yet it also depends on the perspective...

Meanwhile, however, just in case, have you tried: <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd><kbd>**Alt**</kbd><kbd>**Tab**</kbd> instead of <kbd>**Alt**</kbd><kbd>**Shift**</kbd><kbd>**Tab**</kbd>?
It may be a temporary workaround if <kbd>**Alt**</kbd><kbd>**Shift**</kbd> is set in Xorg for layout switching/toggling (i.e. `grp:alt_shift_toggle`) and considering the following:

- [2018-02-28 - Alt+Shift+Backtab for reverse task switching?](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=151314#p397209);
- [2018-04-10 - Bug 392961 on bugs.kde.org](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=392961#c13);
- [2003-06-03 - Bug 59303 on bugs.kde.org](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=59303);
- [2004-07-14 - Bug 865 on bugs.freedesktop.org](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865).

> The X server does not know about any shortcuts -- shortcuts are the domain of the desktop environment.  Maybe in Windows layout-switching and shortcut-recognition happen in the same component, so it can hold off switching layouts until Shift and/or Alt is released to see if maybe another key will be pressed.  But in X, layout switching happens in the server, and as soon as the switching combo is seen, the layout is switched and the combo is dropped.

Source: [GitLab](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/setxkbmap/-/issues/10#note_1620747) (freedesktop.org)

---

For example:
[image: Ctrl+Alt+Tab]

It depends on the current shortcuts and may indeed appear non-comfortable enough (subjective...), yet the wonderful <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is near <kbd>Shift</kbd> on the most of the keyboards and may have been waiting all this time just for you! ^^

---

Related: [[XKB] need to kick hotkeys on release, not press](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/issues/258)